# Dynamic Linq Any syntax

Tags: linq, dynamic-linq

I am trying to figure out how to use Any operator in Linq.Dynamic, here is my test code:

```
var bar = new[] {
    new {Bar = "A", Id = 1},
    new {Bar = "B", Id = 1},
    new {Bar = "C", Id = 2},
    new {Bar = "A", Id = 2},
    new {Bar = "B", Id = 3},
    new {Bar = "C", Id = 3}
}; 
var foo = new[] {
    new {Foo = 1, Id = 1},
    new {Foo = 1, Id = 1},
    new {Foo = 2, Id = 2},
    new {Foo = 2, Id = 2},
    new {Foo = 2, Id = 3},
    new {Foo = 3, Id = 3}
}; 
var res = foo.GroupJoin(bar, x => x.Id, y => y.Id, (x, l) => new { F = x.Foo, Bs = l.Select(b => b.Bar).ToArray() }).ToArray();
var normalLinq = res.Where(x => x.Bs.Any(y => y == "A")).ToArray();
var dynamicLinq = res.AsQueryable().Where("Bs.Any(x => x==\"A\")").ToArray(); //won't work
```

The syntax `"Bs.Any(x => x==\"A\")"` is wrong as dynamic linq doesn't seem to know the lambda expression I put in, and exception is thrown. How do I make it work?

My goal is to parse dynamic search input with this code. If you Linq experts have other better ways to do dynamic search, please suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using this library: http://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Linq.Dynamic/ as far as I know it does not allow lambda expressions. However, there is somebody who extended this library. I have never tried it but it looks promising. http://dynamiclinq.codeplex.com/ Good luck :)

Comment: thank you, and by the way, i figured it out i need to implement Contains() function to do what I wanted.